# How to view total CPU and memory usage of a system user in linux system

Tags: linux, shell, command

I know the top command to see the process of CPU and memory usage, but some users of the system can generate a lot of processes, if I wanna know total CPU and memory usage of an user,I must count it by my own,so,is there a command which can view total CPU and memory usage of a system user in linux system，and order by system username?

Comment: this is not superuser.com, you're asking the wrong community, btw : https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+total+cpu+memory+usage.
Welcome to the internet.

Answer (score 2):

try those oneliners

For CPU:

```
top -b -n 1 -u <user>  | awk 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print sum; }'
```

For memory

```
top -b -n 1 -u <user> | awk 'NR>7 { sum += $10; } END { print sum; }'
```

EDIT:

one script cover all user:

```
for i in `ps -ef | grep -v UID | awk '{print $1}'| sort | uniq`; 
do
    echo "user: " $i;
    top -b -n 1 -u $i | awk 'NR>7 { sum += $9; } END { print "CPU " sum; }'; 
    top -b -n 1 -u $i | awk 'NR>7 { sum += $10; } END { print "MEM " sum; }';
    echo;
done
```

Comment: Think you,I tried,it worked.But this command just shows usage of singer user,can you provide one command which can show usage of per user.I'm not good at LInux,but I need this kind of command,Thank you!

Comment: I have added script to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [smem](http://www.selenic.com/smem/)

```
smem -u -t -k
```